# How to calculate sum of querySnapshot ? with flutter/cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

I successfully read data from Cloud Firestore, but I don't know how to compute the sum of value from a document.

Here is how I get the document data:

```
firestoreInstance.collection("parrainage").get().then((querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
    print("${result.data() } ");  // my input
  });
});
```

---

```
{
  key1: 1,
  key2: 1,
  key3: 1,
  key4: 1,
  key5: 1
}
```

Here is the output I expect:

```
sum= 5;
```

[image]

if I use this in the first collection it return 1 and not 2:

```
final sum = result.data().values.fold<int>(0, (acc, curr) => acc + curr));
print('sum=$sum');
```

But if I use the same code with the second example It's work, but I add manually data, I don't successed to add this data programaticaly

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [fold](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/fold.html) method:

if `result.data()` is a `Map<String, int>`:

```
final sum = result.data().values.fold<int>(0, (acc, curr) => acc + curr));
print('sum=$sum');
```

---

### Full sample with static data

```
void main() {
  final Map<String, int> data = {
    'key1': 1,
    'key2': 0,
    'key3': 1,
    'key4': 1,
    'key5': 1,
  };
  final sum = data.values.fold<int>(0, (acc, curr) => acc + curr);
  print('sum=$sum');
}
```

This prints `sum=4`.

Comment: thank you but I don't understand it return the good value if I have only one key. for example :   key1: 23, return :23.  but if I have key1 :1 key2:0 key3:1 I have a return:1 instread of 2

Comment: Weird, check if you properly used my solution. I added a full sample with static data.

Comment: thank you, it's was my input format who was not good :)

Comment: I speak to speed, not run with my format :( I upload my post

Comment: weird things, I use two firebase format, but in terminal it's the same, but your code doesn't work with one

Comment: In your first example, it seems that the key of the field is `ouicoin: 1, d6d83srr: 1, d6d83sr7` nd the value is `1`. This is definitely a mistake.

Comment: In your second example, you have one field per `key: value` pair. This is fine. You could also have a `Map<Key, Value>`  instead. if the set of keys is dynamic.

Comment: the second example, I add field manually to verify, but in my code I don't successed to create this. I post a demande with no response in stackoverflow, so in the waiting I try an other solution ( example 1) but seems not possible ;(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229257/discussion-between-thierry-and-nitneuq).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 int increment = 1;
 int sum = 0;
 firestoreInstance.collection("parrainage").get().then((querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
          print("${result.data() } ");
          sum += result.data()["key${increment}"];
          increment++;
        });
      });
```

Comment: Than you, but I have no output found in terminal when I    add   sum += result.data()["mykey${increment}"];

Comment: Did u print(sum); after increment++, u need to print inside the forEach because `then` is asynchronous. So for now just print it like I told u to see if it adds or no